# Why NetBeans can't find Mercurial path?

Tags: linux, netbeans, mercurial, linux-mint, flatpak

I have a Linux Mint VM, where I installed formerly NetBeans 12.x (up to 12.6) and now I've updated it to 13.0, all with flatpak, and even starting from a clean setup.

With all those setups, NetBeans can't find Mercurial, even if I really have it in `/usr/bin/hg` available and working (when used from the shell).

From menu Team / Mercurial / Initialize repository... I get the error "Mercurial could not be found", asking to check PATH.
The strange behavior is that if I even browse for Options and Mercurial Executable Path to `/usr/bin` I **can't see** hg in there, while it **is** in the filesystem!

Is NB browsing *somewhere else* when I open `/usr/bin`?
Is it accessing some virtual environment? I'm confused

Comment: For reference, I just did a clean install of `Mint 20.3 Cinnamon VM`, installed Mercurial using apt, got the NetBeans13 install shell script with wget and installed it and tried it but could not reproduce.
I was able to initialize the Mercurial repository without any configuration, and if I open `/usr/bin` using the Browse button on the Team tab in Options, hg shows up there.

Comment: what are the file permissions on the `hg` executable?

Comment: @StayOnTarget That was one of the first checks: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1149 mar 25  2020 /usr/bin/hg`

Comment: @fliedonion That's interesting: I didn't get it with a *wget* but just went straight away with the package manager/flatpak. Maybe it's related to flatpak environment

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution: the flatpak package is indeed at fail, as for some reason it's not seeing my `/usr/bin` but a virtualized (?) directory, where many files are missing - notably `hg` and `hg-ssh`

So I removed the package suggested by the Linux Mint *Software Manager* and installed the package got from the **Apache NetBeans site**, similarly to what @flied-onion did.

What's still missing is that NetBeans relies on the `hgk` application as an hg GUI interface for some functions (see *Team* / *View*). This is unknown to me, and I don't find it in any (recent) Debian flavor.